# I have to 400MB pdf file to 1/2 MB in order to open my website? Or how can I create e-pdf to show on my website from the book?

Tags: pdf

I have to 400MB pdf file to 1/2 MB in order to open my website. Or how can I create e-pdf to show on my website from the book?

I have to open book pdf on my website with pages 616.
I used pdf programmes but they cannot compress enough and my website cannot open the file immediately

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question.

If you want to show only one page of a large PDF file, you can extract that page simply by opening the book in a PDF viewer.

Then, depending on the PDF viewer:

- Select print, set PDF as destination. In the following you can then select the page(s) to 'print' to the output file.
- In some viewers, you have to Export to PDF, then do the same.

Then you have a PDF of only the part you want...

Comment: I want to open all book as pdf on web, not one page :( because of the 400 MB size, chrome does not open, it takes 5 minutes :(

Comment: Chrome needs to render the PDF, which _will_ take some time. Maybe you can specify the use of an external PDF viewer (Firefox permits that). The only other solution I see is to use a Javascript which can download page - by - page. 400MB is huge. If you have many images, check if the images cannot be reduced in resolution. If they are plots, graphs etc, check if you are saving them in the PDF as vector graphic (NOT rasterized)